# Ideas for implementing a shift scheduler? calendar? custom content type?

Tags: nodes, datetime

for our NPO we need the following feature: We have a bar, hotel and restaurant, and there are some fixed shifts ie. 7am to 12am, 12am to 7pm and so on, the whole week;

- People enter their wanted work shift themselves;
- There has to be an overview what shifts are set and which ones miss workers. A table for the current and next week, coloured with the user names;

I thought about a custom content type in a module, where the time (start, end) are set by the admin and can be changed from time to time. On click in the calendar resp. the overview panel, the node is prepopulated with auto_title and the times and the entityreference to the user.

And ideas if there is a view plugin which could do the overview, or do i need to code that myself?

I am aware of : shift_scheduler module (sandbox)

Comment: I think a custom entity type sounds more appropriate than a custom content type for your needs.

Comment: thx for the input you both, I am checking loads of nice modules and possibilities these days. Hopefully I remind to come back to you here asap.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are aware of the calendar module https://drupal.org/project/calendar
It has a very nice integration with views, and you could create a calender from template for a specific content type that has date fields in seconds (that generates also a view of it per week).
Of course for the case you have described you will need custom coding, surely the Drupal Ajax Framework and some other stuff... but that sounds more like fun :)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I am still into this issue, and try and learn a lot. So I leave the question open.